# how to install rpmrebuild in openshift for restricted user?

Tags: openshift, puppet, yum

hi dear in need to install puppet in my openshift app so i must run

```
rpm -ivh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
```

from this site:

```
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_el.html
```

but i get this error:

```
bash: /bin/rpm: Permission denied
```

so i need to run new rpm for my restricted user by Hacking RPMs with rpmrebuild

so i need to install rpmrebuild by :

```
yum install rpmrebuild
```

but i get this error:

```
    error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

so  is there anybody to know have i could install rpmrebuild or puppet in my openshift acount by ssh and putty?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot normally install `rpm` packages without root privileges.

Your best option is probably to get the [puppet gem](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_gem.html). The documentation suggests `sudo`, which is not available to you. Don't worry, though - gems can generally be installed by [unpriviliged users](http://www.binarytides.com/quick-tip-installing-ruby-gems-in-the-users-home-directory/) just fine.